# laravel back-end scaffolding for rest api

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-package

I want to create a new Laravel project with Laravel Passport.

I was looking for the controller and the APIs for auth (login/ logout/ register/ forgot password)

if I wanted to use normal auth I would go with `Laravel Breeeze` but I just need apis.

does any body know any package?

Comment: Laravel Breeze already includes what you need so you don't need any other package.

Comment: @CanCelik but laravel breeze will provide some blade files and controllers without api. so I should create some new controllers for api and replace it. am I right?

Comment: If you don't need any views, then you can use Laravel Sanctum

Comment: @CanCelik but laravel Sanctum works with livewire... I need just some normal controllers...not livewire

Comment: Laravel Sanctum doesn't use or require livewire. Please check the documentation here => https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum

Comment: @CanCelik yes I know, by default sanctum is installed on a new laravel project. I'm looking for the codes that we should write in the controllers for the route /login /register /forgot-password

Comment: You said sanctum works with livewiere which it doesn't. You said you need API auth but looking for login/register/forgot-password routes. I think you're little bit confused on what you need. Documentation URL I provided in my previous comment has enough codes to get you started for the API authentication.